# Cherrypy: Why would globals() sometimes be missing the functions in this module?

Tags: python, cherrypy

Why would `globals()` sometimes be missing the functions in this module? Assume it is called by another module, and may not have run any of these functions yet.

I pull up my web page, which is located in the code as `a_builder`, and sometimes, instead of the web page retrieving the data in `a_builder`, it instead returns the "Sorry, this page was not found."

So far, the most consistent occurrence of this happening, is if I have made changes to the content for the web page, found in a_builder's code. I then pull the repo to the test server, and reset the server. But after I do this, can cause all web pages with content associated with each builder in the list to also show same "Sorry, page not found.."

I do not review these builders/web pages often enough to know for sure that these edits are the only cause of it or the only time it happens.

The site exposed code, passing in a list of builders, which are web pages:

```
@cherrypy.expose(['a_builder','b_builder', 'c_builder',...])
@cherrypy.tools.validate_user()
def generic_builder(self, *args, **kw):
    from urlparse import urlparse
    path = urlparse(cherrypy.url()).path
    if len(path) > 1:
        kw['page'] = path[1:].replace('-','_') # drop /
    else:
        kw['page'] = '/'
    import survey_builders
    return survey_builders.generic_builder(get_uid(), kw)
```

Here is an example of the function being returned in the above code:

```
def generic_builder(user_id, kw):
    # look in the 'page' kwarg for the builder to call
    if kw['page'] in globals():
        this_function = globals().pop(kw['page'])
        return this_function(user_id)
    else:
        return cherrypy.bootstrap_page("""<p>Sorry, this page was not found...</p>"""...)
```

Comment: Your code looks dangerous. What happens if you access e.g. `/exit` ?

Comment: The structure of your question is a bit vage and gives me a headache... start with topic, explaining what you do and end with the question. Do not start with the question because the content to know what you're talking about isn't pulled yet!

Comment: ..*I retrieve a_builder, which* ..either you constructed a builder or received one from someone else... please clarify by modifying your question. Do not answer in comment! Retrieve is used for example as such " pulling something from a trash-bin". (not criticizing language skills... just get clarity on the topic).

Comment: I made edits to the question. Let me know if I'm clarifying or confusing further.

Comment: You are modifying globals, which breaks it for the next query. + I agree with @Tobias: your code is overly dynamic being extremely dangerous. You might want to maintain a mapping *reading func from there w/o removing them*. Also, consider using `default` method instead of messing with manual URL parsing: this is what web framework is for.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'll take this back to the team and review.